# GCC #define statement bytes wrong order

Tags: c, gcc, x86, c-preprocessor, endianness

For a project I am working on I use magic numbers.
This macro is used to define one

```
#define BOOTSIGNATURE 0xAA55
```

However, when I HEXDUMP the resulting file, where it should say AA55 it says 55 AA.

Is GCC Mixing up endianness, or am I? This project is for the x86 processor. AA 55 needs to be in that specific order. I could just exchange the bytes, but I am curious as to why GCC does this.

Comment: As the x86 is little endian, I can see why GCC thinks that this is wanted behaviour. However, for me, AA55 is kind of like a string of bytes, needed in that specific order. How can I achieve the needed behaviour?

Comment: You could define it as a string (array) of bytes instead of a single integer. I don't know how you are using it, so I don't know if it will work without other modifications. `#define BOOTSIGNATURE ((char[]){0xAA,0x55})`. You can also just check the architecture and switch the order, leaving a comment so you know why.

Comment: The binary is written in the same endianness as the machine, when it's loaded again it will be read correctly, if that's what you're worried about.

Comment: nope it's a magic number, that's not a sollution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0xAA55` is an `int` and so you are subject to the endianness of your machine. I would store this as a char array:

```
const unsigned char BOOTSIGNATURE[] = {0xAA, 0x55};
```

Comment: Great. So if I were to cast this to a unsigned short int it would work as part of a struct?

Comment: Yes, you could cast that to an unsigned short int. How are you dealing with the rest of your file? Is it also little endian? In which case this bit is just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: Nope, not a problem. The rest of the file is in the GCC domain (written and read both by GCC style compiled c code) The boot signature (as the name says ;) ) Is read by the BIOS to verify that the first 512 of my disk image is valid for booting. That's why the order of the bytes matters there, not elsewhere. When another sector is read, endianness influence is cancelled out because it's read using the same endianness. The bios however, requires these bytes to be in a specific order.

Comment: Oh, BTW I am aware that endianness is a feature of the x86, not GCC, but just said that to point out that reading is "out of my hands" in this case, not in any other case.

Answer (score 2):

Preprocessor macros don't show up in the compiled object files -- they're not seen at all by the compiler.  If you just had that `#define` and never used it anywhere, there'd be no trace of it.

If you used it in code somewhere, it would likely show up as a constant in an instruction (e.g. to load a constant into a register or memory).  If you used it to initialize static data, it would show up as a constant in the data segment:

```
// Global variable definition
#define BOOTSIGNATURE 0xAA55
uint16_t my_global = BOOTSIGNATURE;
```

If you compile the above and look at the data segment, it looks like this:

```
$ gcc -c test.c
$ objdump -s test.o
[...]
Contents of section .data:
 0000 55aa0000                             U...
```

As you can see, the two bytes are stored in memory in little-endian order `55 AA` (the leading `0000` is the segment offset in hex).

If you want to control the endianness of the data, then store it as an explicit byte array:

```
uint8_t my_global[] = {0xAA, 0x55};
```

This will always store the bytes in the order specified.

Comment: I am aware of this off course, and obviously I used it somewhere. This byte array can be cast to an short int then?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write portable code, you'd make use of functions to force a given byte order.  For example, [these functions](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/endian.3.html) allow you to convert a 16-bit value in native host-byte-order to either big-endian or little-endian, depending on what order you need it in your file.

```
#define BOOTSIGNATURE 0xAA55

struct bootheader {
   uint16_t    signature_be;
} header;

header.signature_be = htobe16( BOOTSIGNATURE);
```

I like using a `_le` or `_be` suffix on variables and structure elements with non-host-byte-order.

Since you need big-endian, you can use `htons()` from `arpa/inet.h`, but I'm not a big fan of that method.  I don't think the name is as clear as `htobe16`, and you don't have functions for converting to/from little-endian byte order.

Answer (score -2):

Simplest sollution: use the integer form of the hex value so the corresponding binary will result in the same magic number! In this case that would be 43605

Comment: I'm not sure that's any better. That's just 0x55AA. You still have the same endian issues.

Comment: no realised that too. Just updated the value, and now I don't have to change anything throughout the rest of my code.